# What does “hand with 2 arrows icon” status icon represent?

Tags: notification-icons

Can anyone help me identify this icon that looks like "a hand with 2 arrows"
[image: notification icon]

Comment: Looks like data saver.

Answer (score 2):

It's called Air Browse and it was available in some older Galaxy phones.

You can disable it by going to *Menu --> Settings --> Section "Motion" --> motions and gestures --> Air Browse*

[Details here](http://www.samsung.com/in/support/skp/htg/17035#none)